# delete Site collections sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell

I need to delete all site collections that contains personal in  it.
I get all the site collections by the cmdlet

```
$sites= get-spsite -limit all| Where {$_.url -like "*personal*"}
foreach($site in $sites)
{
Remove-spsite -identity $site
}
```

I get an error `cannot convert spsite to Spsitepipebind`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of removing sites in foreach try passing it to Remove-SPSite using pipeline:

---

```
Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | Where-Object { $_.Url -Like "*personal*" } | Remove-SPSite
```

Or shorter version:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | ? Url -like *personal* | Remove-SPSite
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code it needs to be $_. and not $.